# Regex not matching name in filepath

Tags: regex, bash

I have a folder with ipa files. I need to identify them by having a `appstore` or `enterprise` in the filename.

```
mles:drive-ios-swift mles$ ls build
com.project.drive-appstore.ipa                                   
com.project.test.swift.dev-enterprise.ipa
com.project.drive_v2.6.0._20170728_1156.ipa
```

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash -veE

fileNameRegex="**appstore**"

for appFile in build-test/*{.ipa,.apk}; do
if [[ $appFile =~ $fileNameRegex ]]; then
    echo "$appFile Matches"
else
    echo "$appFile Does not match"
fi
done
```

However nothing matches:

```
mles:drive-ios-swift mles$ ./test.sh 
build-test/com.project.drive-appstore.ipa Does not match
build-test/com.project.drive_v2.6.0._20170728_1156.ipa Does not match
build-test/com.project.test.swift.dev-enterprise.ipa Does not match
build-test/*.apk Does not match
```

How would the correct script look like to match `build-test/com.project.drive-appstore.ipa`?

Comment: Try `fileNameRegex=".*appstore.*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between the *glob* string match with a regex match. For a greedy glob match like `*` you can just use the test operator with `==`,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fileNameGlob='*appstore*'
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Single quote the regex string   

for appFile in build-test/*{.ipa,.apk}; do        
    # To skip non-existent files
    [[ -e $appFile ]] || continue

    if [[ $appFile == *${fileNameGlob}* ]]; then
        echo "$appFile Matches"
    else
        echo "$appFile Does not match"
    fi
done
```

produces a result

```
build-test/com.project.drive_v2.6.0._20170728_1156.ipa Does not match
build-test/com.project.drive-appstore.ipa Matches
build-test/com.project.test.swift.dev-enterprise.ipa Does not match
```

(or) with a regex use greedy match `.*` as

```
fileNameRegex='.*appstore.*'
if [[ $appFile =~ ${fileNameRegex} ]]; then
    # rest of the code
```

---

That said to match your original requirement to match `enterprise` or `appstore` string in file name use extended glob matches in `bash`

Using glob:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
fileExtGlob='*+(enterprise|appstore)*'

if [[ $appFile == ${fileExtGlob} ]]; then
    # rest of the code
```

and with regex,

```
fileNameRegex2='enterprise|appstore'
if [[ $appFile =~ ${fileNameRegex2} ]]; then
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for the line with how to skip non existant files. Very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to match appstore and enterprise in a filename:

```
for i in build-test/*; do if [[ $i =~ appstore|enterprise ]]; then echo $i; fi; done
```